# MySQL WorkBench: dumping whole data base in one sql file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MysQL 5.6 and MySQL 6.1 WorkBench. I found [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html) on how to dump whole data base
with values, but the problem is it separates every table into one sql file. How can I dump whole data base to only one sql file?

Comment: First G! [search result](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) in case you are okay taking a dump not from workbench.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Option "Export to Self-Contained File to dump the selected database(s) into one sql file:

[image]